# Resuming final_suspend causes error, not destroys coroutine

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-coroutine

James McNellis in his presentation “Introduction to C++ Coroutines" (https://youtu.be/ZTqHjjm86Bw?t=1898) says the following:

A coroutine is destroyed when:

- final_suspend is resumed,
- coroutine_handle<>::destroy() is called,

whichever happens first.

In my tests I see (VS 2015, VS 2017 RC), that resuming coroutine that is suspended on final_suspend causes an error instead:

> Unhandled exception at 0x010B9EDD in Awaits2017.exe: RangeChecks instrumentation code detected an out of range array access. occurred

Any ideas what might be going on here?

```
#include <experimental/resumable>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::experimental;

struct Coro
{
    coroutine_handle<> m_coro;
    Coro(coroutine_handle<> coro) : m_coro(coro) {}

    struct promise_type
    {
        Coro get_return_object()
        {
            return Coro(coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this));
        }

        auto initial_suspend() { return false; }
        auto final_suspend() { return true; }
        void return_void() {}
    };
};

Coro simple()
{
    co_return;
}

int main()
{
    Coro c = simple();
    c.m_coro.resume(); // runtime error here
}
```

Comment: In the published TS initia/final_suspend cannot return bool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of thumb:

- If `final_suspend` returns `true`, you should call `coroutine_handle<>::destroy()`, instead of `resume()`.
- If `final_suspend` returns `false`, you should not call `destroy()` as well, the coroutine will cleanup itself.

Note that the coroutine included in VS 2015 is not what James McNellis shown in the video (the proposal has many revisions), and the description:

> final_suspend is resumed

may be confusing. It does not really mean `resume()` is called.